# Keeping the content and the title next to each other

Tags: html, css

Hello I am busy creating a website with only 1 page and I walked into a problem that I can not fix. the "title" of each html  is displayed at the very left of the page and the content should stand right next to it. the problem is that the content displays under the title.

an example of the website: [website on codepen](http://codepen.io/reshadf/full/qopaF)

Can someone tell me how to fix this with keeping the possibilities to stretch the title with the content?

the section structure is as follows:

```
        <section class="experience">
            <h2 class="title">experience</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
    </section>
```

Comment: ... <h2 style="display: inline;" ...

Comment: nope i want the title to be vertically as you see in the link. the only thing that must be different is that the text must be able to stand next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a style to the title/content of display: inline should be enough to fix this.